# Using entry widget as stdin in asynchronous chat program

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-asyncio

I have developed an asynchronous console chat program. Then I decided to develop an asynchronous GUI chat program.

The server side is running on console. The server is managing the communication process between clients.

I have two client programs. One of them is a console, the other one is a GUI program. When the console program sends messages, they are printed on the Text widget of the GUI program.

However when I sent messages on the GUI program, the messages are displayed on the console window of the other client program only after the client which runs on console writes messages to the other client.

The `write` function of the console program is as follows:

```
    async def write(self, writer):
        t = threading.Thread(
            target=lambda: writer.write(
                f"{self.nick}: {sys.stdin.readline()}".encode()
            )
        )
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        t.join(0.1)
        await writer.drain()
```

This function accomplishes the task as I want.

The `write` function of the GUI program is as follows:

```
    async def write(self, writer):
        if self.data:
            data = self.data
            self.data = ""
            t = threading.Thread(
                target=lambda: writer.write(
                    f"{self.nick}: {data}\n".encode()
                )
            )
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
            t.join(0.1)
            await writer.drain()
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
```

And this function is not working as I want.

`self.data` is a variable that gets the text in the `tk.Entry` field. It was defined in the `__init__` function of the class.

```
        self.entry = tk.Entry(
            master=self.bottom_frame,
            width=50
        )
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", lambda event: self.callback())

        self.data = ""
```

The `self.callback()` function is as follows:

```
    def callback(self):
        self.data = self.entry.get()
        self.entry.delete("0", "end")
        self.update()
        self.update_idletasks()
```

So, what I was trying to do here was, when I press the `<Return>`, the content of the `self.entry` is passed to `self.data` variable. According to the `self.write` function, there's a condition like `if self.data` which is used for sending messages when `self.data` is not an empty value. If the condition is not met, I decided to wait the function with `await asyncio.sleep(0.1)`.

As I said, the gui program reads the messages without any problem, however it can't send messages asynchronously to the console client program. The console client program needs to send a new message to see the messages come from the GUI client.

What should I do to send messages asynchronously on GUI application?

Below are the whole codes:

**Server:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/q04w3et3huegrao/server.py

**Client1:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/h7seeuoylvnpezq/client1.py

**Client2:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/uz4zn3vjfcc3mrj/client2.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probem is solved. The asynchronous `write` function is changed as below:

```
    async def write(self, writer):

        def inner():
            data = self.entry.get()
            self.entry.delete("0", "end")
            self.entry.unbind_all("<Return>")
            t = threading.Thread(
                target=lambda: writer.write(
                    f"{self.nick}: {data}\n".encode()
                )
            )
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
            t.join(0.1)

        self.entry.bind("<Return>", lambda event: inner())
        await writer.drain()
```